# Permission denied when using Jenkins to run commands

Tags: permissions, jenkins

I'm using a Jenkins job to execute some shell commands where directories and files need to be created but I get a `Permission Denied` error. I'm running Jenkins as a daemon (followed [this tutorial from the Jenkins website](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu)). The jenkins that runs the job is user `jenkins` and has group `nogroup`. The commands create `folder1/folder2` which each have a number of files in both. When I use `chown` for both of them to be `jenkins`, the permission error goes away and all the files get produced, so this works but is there a way I can set it up so that I don't need to manually create `folder1/folder2` and change ownership to `jenkins` ahead of time?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a parent folder that belongs to jenkins:nogroup. My guess is that your script is attempting to create folder1 and folder2 inside a parent directory which does not belong to the jenkins user. As long as Jenkins has permissions to write to the parent folder your script should be able to create any directories or files that are required for your tests.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this, so I have a few questions. Did you mean to change the parent directory to be owned by jenkins and belong to group nogroup? Everything currently belongs to me, boose, if I made that change how would that affect me cd'ing into directories and reading files, etc? Also the parent directory would be trunk (trunk/folder1/folder2), do I need to do anything to trunk's parent? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. Try using chmod command (http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm), this might help you. I believe this is because of the operating system and not because of Jenkins. Try finding out the answers in Unix forum also. : )